# Buying food from non-Shomer-Shabbos restaurants and stores

Tags: shabbat, kashrut-kosher, food, transactions, trust-neemanut

Is buying food from non-Shomer-Shabbos restaurants and stores disallowed? On what grounds? What is the level of prohibition? Are there any exceptions?
(Might it apply less, perhaps, to certain foods, for example non-bread/meat/wine/shulchan melachim?)

Could I eat kosher food cooked by my mother if, G-d forbid, she weren't shomer Shabbos?

Comment: Is this restaurant owned and/or operated by a Jew?

Comment: There are two fish shops in the same high street local to me, both of which sell only kosher fish and are owned by Jews but one opens on Shabbat and the other does not. I usually buy in the one that closes on Shabbat, even if I am buying on a Thursday when I can pretty much guarantee that the fish was not delivered on Shabbat.

Comment: @DoubleAA well, since I'm not asking for a psak, I'd invite respondents to consider both of those cases :)

Comment: @CashCow, even Wednesday should be fine. As a general rule, fishmongers don't like to keep inventory on hand longer than necessary (often including when it would go to waste). My local grocers (I only get fish I can identify ע”פ the OU) get fish every day of the week but Monday, as there is no ability to order fish on Sunday from the wholesalers, or so I've heard. They're makpid on not selling anything older than a few days, so you can be pretty sure that it's not benefitting from a chillul Shabbat.

Comment: Fwiw, when I lived in _chutz laaretz_, I bought food from non-Jewish-owned stores open on _Shabas_ **all the time**, and so did every (or at least pretty much every) other Jew in my community.

Comment: Spinoff question maybe: Is there any problem buying and using non-food products from such stores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quickly go over only.

### I.  Taking the words of the seller concerning components and process

#### SA YD  siman 119 adress the subject.

There are several cases.

The basic question is if you can believe that food is Kasher when you ask someone who himself eats non Kosher foods (sayif 1), who doesn't eat but  sells to others non Kasher foods (sayif 2) ; if someone who is unreliable for a rule X can be asked about a rule Y (sayif 4) ; if you provide  ingredients,  can we have confidence that the dispenser uses them only (sayif 3).

Concerning non Shomer Shabbat Jew see sayif 7, it seems that who is Mechallel Shabbat is  unreliable for Kashrut questions.

If you ask about buying Kosher food in a Jewish store which sells  non Kosher food  or is known as lying regarding some products origin,  there is a knass (sayif 4) to not buy from him even foods which are doubtless.

> `Are there any exceptions?`

#### To buy  Kosher food in a non Kosher store.

To buy Foods which potential prohibition Deorayta,  as foods containing wine,  meat,  fish, we need  to see a double sealed (שתי חותמות). Potential prohibition Derabanan,  needs one sealed only. Some poskim require double sealed for Deorayta problems  with  suspected  Jews only,  with   non Jew,  one  sealed is good enough. Bread which can be manufactured by a non Jew owner needs to be sealed (because the maximum of leniency concerning Pat Akum is for pat palter,  not the bread which the NJ made at home for himself.) (SA YD 118, 1).

### II.   Non Jew's made foods

> `Shulchan Melachim`

#### The prohibition of Bishul Nochri.

mainly treated in SA YD 113.

Let's adress the problem of bishul (when there is no problem with ingredients).
The prohibition of Bishul Nochri apply when two conditions are fulfilled: 1. not eaten  raw, 2.  brought at kings table. (Or a mixture of foods in which the main part meets this conditions). Hard boiled eggs are prohibited.

Roasted Chickpeas ( ארבעס) and similar seeds are allowed,  small fried fishs.

Bakery bread is a sufficiently known issue. (according to some poskim if the bread is brush with eggs yolk,  there is no  kula of pat palter, because of the eggs)

> `Could I eat kosher food cooked by my mother if, G-d forbid, she weren't shomer Shabbos?`

The question is if the prohibition of Pat Kutim shel baale Batim is extended to Jewish people who has a status of Mumar (renegade). Concerning non Jew's products, wine and bread have similarities, "Stam Yenam" and "Pat Nochri",   They result from decrees because of inter marriage risk,  poskim (SA YD 112, 1 Baer Heytev sk 1)  discussed Hava Amina to allow bread of monks  (who have no children).  For  a renegade, in contrast with wine, there is no problem of chatnut Lechaora and the pat is allowed. *It seems that the Gezera for Mumar is limited to wine only (SA YD 124, 8)*